# Lifetime of temporary rvalue referenced object

Tags: c++, c++14, language-lawyer

Suppose you have this code (in c++14) :

```
auto && a = a_function_returning_a_temp_rvalue();
```

Where is stored the returned value, when is its destructor called, is `a` `const` (considering the function doesn't return a `const` ), how is it specified in the standard ?
(is it even legal)

Also, do you confirm, the temporary is really bound to `a`, and no `operator=` neither constructors will be called ?

It compiles on g++ and avoid typing long template classes, but before using it, I would like to check if it's clearly stated in c++14

Comment: `auto` works as template argument deduction except some exceptions.

Comment: I know, but I'm wondering about the rvalue's lifetime (I guess, since it's bound to `a`, it's the same as `a`, but I would like to know how and where it's said in the standard)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is guaranteed to work.

[12.2/4-5]

> There are two contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. ...
>
> The second context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.  The temporary to which the reference is bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound persists for the lifetime of the reference except:
>
> - A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the call.
> - The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement is not extended; the temporary is destroyed at the end of the full-expression in the return statement.
> - A temporary bound to a reference in a *new-initializer* persists until the completion of the full-expression containing the *new-initializer*.

No constructor or `operator=` is called to initialize `a`, and `a` is not `const` if it doesn't need to be.

Answer (score 2):

The rule is in [class.temporary]:

> There are three contexts in which temporaries are destroyed at a different point than the end of the full-expression. [...] The third context is when a reference is bound to a temporary.116 The temporary to which the reference is
>   bound or the temporary that is the complete object of a subobject to which the reference is bound **persists for the lifetime of the reference** except:
>   — A temporary object bound to a reference parameter in a function call (5.2.2) [...]
>   — The lifetime of a temporary bound to the returned value in a function return statement (6.6.3) is [...]
>   — A temporary bound to a reference in a new-initializer (5.3.4) persists until [...]

In this example:

```
auto && a = a_function_returning_a_temp_rvalue();
```

I'm assuming the function returns something of type `T` (as opposed to `T&` or `T&&`). In this case, we do have a temporary bound to a reference, and none of those exceptions apply. Hence, the lifetime of that temporary is extended for the lifetime of `a`.